# How to label local variables in x64dbg

Tags: tools, debuggers, x64dbg

As the title stands, I want to label local variables ([ebp - x] addresses) the same way I do with functions and global variables. What I've learned:

- I found no way to label locals in the debugger window.
- There's `Locals` tab in the bottom panel. I can give names to locals there, but they don't propagate to the main window.
- I can rename variables in the decompiler window, but again, they don't sync with the debugger window.

If x64dbg lacks this functionality, is there any plugin that achieves this?

Comment: Often reverse engineers do dynamic and static analysis side by side. You start off with Binja/IDA/radare2 and annotate information from the dynamic analysis. These tools can save this information and offer more functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to label local variables in x64dbg:

1. In x64dbg, follow in dump at address of local var (like this [ebp-4]). Right click at this address and select Add label, then name the label.

[image]

Now in the CPU window, local var is displayed like the following picture:

[image]

2. Try the labeless plugin : https://github.com/a1ext/labeless/ to sync from IDA to x64dbg.

Regards;

Answer (score 3):

Local variables labeling is not yet supported by *x64dbg* and as far as I know there's no plugin to achieve that.

However, you can still label a specific memory address. You can do this by selecting the address and press <kbd>:</kbd>, or right click it and select *Label >> Label Current Address*.

If you want this functionality you can ask for it on the [x64dbg's Github repository](https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbg) or even implement it by yourself.